# Combining static assert and assert?

Tags: c++, assert, static-assert

I have a function that looks like this:

```
int div_round_up(int x, int y) {
    /**
     *  This function only works for positive divisor and non-negative dividend!!
     */
    assert(y > 0 && x >= 0);
    if (x == 0)
        return 0;
    return (x - 1) / y + 1;
}
```

It won't work with `y <= 0` or `x < 0`. That's ok with me, I can even dynamically check for right values, but I would like to check statically, when someone feeds it wrong values. If I defined x and y as unsigned, they would get silently converted from negative values to huge positive values which would produce erroneous result, so I don't want that. I would like to make compilation fail when someone attempts to feed it negative values like in `div_round_up(variable, -7)`. What should I do?

Comment: Hmm... you might have some trouble there. You realize `7` and `-7` have the same type, right?

Comment: You can't - unless ISO 'C++' committee decides to get smarter. Eventually you could try writing a proposal to them. I already sketched the basics but really don't want to bother with anything more. You can check it here - https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/6qGR67u-Z9I . Or try using some different language like 'D' for example. Alternatively you can write another templated version of your function and instance it differently when compile-constants are used.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't do that - static_assert don't work that way.

Comment: However, if you're ok with compiler specific directives, there's SAL.  Something akin to `_Ret_range_(0, INT_MAX) int div_round_up(_In_range_(0, INT_MAX) int x, _In_range_(1, INT_MAX) int y)`.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916382.aspx

Comment: @Brian I do realize that. I know that I can't solve this via some kind of type checking, I would like to know if there is some kind of compile time value checking I can apply.

Comment: @MooingDuck Thank, you! That's really interesting.

Comment: learn something new everyday. I assumed that the compiler would barf in the unsigned x called with x == -7 case

Comment: @pm100 at first I didn't even test for that, but I just did and it didn't even warn me (not with my IDE settings anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To verify a number at compile time (which is what `static_assert` does), it has to be known at compile time. To see why this is needed, consider that something like `div_round_up(read_integer_from_file(), read_keyboard_character())`. The obvious drawback of doing that is that you have to *know* the numbers at compile time.

The easiest way is to make them template parameters, which allows you to leave the implementation of the function (almost) the same:

```
template<int x, int y>
int div_round_up() {
    static_assert(y > 0 && x >= 0, "This function only works for positive divisor and non-negative dividend");
    if (x == 0)
        return 0;
    return (x - 1) / y + 1;
}
```

It can be called as `div_round_up<3, 4>()` and [will fail the compilation when the `static_assert` fires](https://ideone.com/KJE28U).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using gcc or clang you can include a macro

```
#define div_round_up(a, b) (__builtin_constant_p(b) ? drus(a, b) : drud(a, b))
```

and two different function where `drus` includes a static assertion for b while `drud` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap you can do it with some magic(one nonamed russian code guru told me this trick)

```
#define check2(x) typedef char checkVal[(x)?1:-1];
int main() {
    check2(3<4);
    check2(5<4);
    return 0;
}
```

but also in this case there is one limit. Compiler should know result of this value. In any another case it`s imossible(IMHO).

Comment: Isn't it just obfuscated/weirdly portable static_assert equivalent?

Comment: yeap this is eq to static_assert, but have one difference it can be used without C++11(as I remember static_assert introducing in it). it using one intresting idea of typedef, that we can redefine an alias.

Comment: @user1687327: It has to be used by the _caller_ though, it can't be inside the function.  It also means the function can only be used with literals and not variables.  So this is highly limiting.